# free webservice with xsd and wsdl both

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am looking for a webservice

1. which is free to user
2. has xsd
3. has wsdl

I have searched a lot but most of the webservices that are there are having only the wsdl and no xsd.

I would really appreciate if some one could post a link

Comment: Can you show us one webservice that has a wsdl an no xsd? It would be interesting...

Comment: I think OP means: *XSD embedded inside WSDL*

Comment: Please be more clear. Most WSDL contain an XSD embedded in them, even if all that XSD does is to import other, external, XSD schemas. The only exception would be the WSDL for a service which only used primitive types (an RPC-style service).

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific. I am a beginer in web service usage.However I do know that and thanks for clarifying once again that xsd is part of wsdl. What I meant is I want a webservice which is using an external xsd with import statement. I want to experiment with such a kind of webservice. Most of the websevices that I found had xsd as part of wsdl noo external xsd

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL. The XSD is embedded inside the WSDL.

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific. I am a beginer in web service usage.However I do know that and thanks for clarifying once again that xsd is part of wsdl. What I meant is I want a webservice which is using an external xsd with import statement. I want to experiment with such a kind of webservice. Most of the websevices that I found had xsd as part of wsdl noo external xsd

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Web Service where XSD is not embedded inside WSDL file, then look for JAX-WS Web Services. In JAX-WS style, the XSD is not embedded inside the WSDL file.